# Как в EditText сделать форматированный ввод номер мобильного телефона?[Android]

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Как на андроид EditText сделать так чтобы ввод осуществлялся по следующему шаблону:

```
+7(927)444-44-44
```

И далее из него получить:
9274444444

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Один в один [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106859/how-to-format-a-phone-number-using-phonenumberutils)

Comment: Вот ещё одна статья на эту тему: https://habrahabr.ru/company/tcsbank/blog/312968/. А также http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788386/set-unchangeable-some-part-of-edittext-android.

Answer (score 3):

Даю наводку: [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Полагаю, с дальнейшим вы в состоянии разобраться самостоятельно.

Comment: Конкретно не получается написать алгоритм в обработчике, так чтобы вводился номер по шаблону, и ограничить кол-во символов до 11, т.к. после нарушается форматирование. Также необходимо чтобы вначале была фиксированна +7, и ее нельзя было бы удалить! Короче надо сделать как в автоматах оплаты сотовой связи!

Comment: Смотрел, не получается! Можно на прмере?

Comment: По ссылке как раз пример использования и имеется. Так же, обратите внимание на [`PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher`][1].
Приведите соответствующий код и задавайте конкретные вопросы, а не по принципу  "у меня ничего не получается, сделайте всё за меня".

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html

Comment: Смотрел! Не получается. Вы не могли бы показать это на конкретном примере? Просто в layout закинуть EditText и в активити выполнить слежение за набором номера, если это так просто. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: библиотека, делающая ровно то, что вы хотите — [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText)

Comment: @ilyarasputin, то есть вы мне предлагаете сделать вашу работу за вас? Нет уж, для этого есть соответствующие ресурсы — фриланс-биржи. Вам дали уже достаточно информации, которую вы, при минимальном умственном усилии, можете превратить в работающее решение. Не хотите  думать сами — платите деньги тому, кто сделает работу за вас. Или меняйте профессию.

Comment: Фиговая наводка. Я как-то день потратил, чтобы почти без багов написать свой анализатор. Большинство примеров идут с багами, ну а вы не постарались даже привести свой вариант. Жалко минусов, так бы поставил.

Answer (score 1):

вот мое решение

```
aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String formatted;
        String regex1 = "(\\+\\d)(\\d{3})";
        String regex2 = "(.+ )(\\d{3})$";
        String regex3 = "(.+\\-)(\\d{2})$";

        // буду реализвывать ввод телефона в формате +х (ххх) ххх-хх-хх
        if (s.toString().matches(regex1)) {
            formatted = String.valueOf(s).replaceFirst(regex1, "$1 ($2) ");
            aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().setText(formatted);
            aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().setSelection(formatted.length());
        } else if (s.toString().matches(regex2)) {
            formatted = String.valueOf(s).replaceFirst(regex2, "$1$2-");
            aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().setText(formatted);
            aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().setSelection(formatted.length());
        } else if (s.toString().matches(regex3) && s.length() < 18) {
            formatted = String.valueOf(s).replaceFirst(regex3, "$1$2-");
            aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().setText(formatted);
            aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().setSelection(formatted.length());
        }
    }
});
```

а достать цифры можно так

```
    String number = aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText().getText().toString().replaceAll("^(\\+7)|\\D+","");
```

Comment: `aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText()` - это типа объект EditText чтоли?

Comment: А что за объект aq?

Comment: @zayn1991, похоже, что да, человек не стал создавать отдельный идентификатор для `aq.id(R.id.etPhone).getEditText()` и решил нас помучать.

Comment: Сильно костыльное решение - только свиду верно выглядит.

Answer (score 1):

Форматирует вводимый номер телефона под формат +7 (ххх) ххх-хх-хх
Также там присутствует фича, чтобы при редактировании текста где-то по середине, выделение текста оставалось там же. Просто и, вроде бы, надёжно.
В отличии от примера кода с регулярками в этом посте - нормально работает удаление текста в конце и в произвольных местах

```
phoneEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    private var mSelfChange = false

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (s == null || mSelfChange) {
            return
        }

        val preparedStr = s.replace(Regex("(\\D*)"), "")
        var resultStr = ""
        for (i in preparedStr.indices) {
            resultStr = when (i) {
                0 -> resultStr.plus("+7 (")
                1 -> resultStr.plus(preparedStr[i])
                2 -> resultStr.plus(preparedStr[i])
                3 -> resultStr.plus(preparedStr[i])
                4 -> resultStr.plus(") ".plus(preparedStr[i]))
                5 -> resultStr.plus(preparedStr[i])
                6 -> resultStr.plus(preparedStr[i])
                7 -> resultStr.plus("-".plus(preparedStr[i]))
                8 -> resultStr.plus(preparedStr[i])
                9 -> resultStr.plus("-".plus(preparedStr[i]))
                10 -> resultStr.plus(preparedStr[i])
                else -> resultStr
            }
        }

        mSelfChange = true
        val oldSelectionPos = phoneEditText.selectionStart
        val isEdit = phoneEditText.selectionStart != phoneEditText.length()
        phoneEditText.setText(resultStr)
        if (isEdit) {
            phoneEditText.setSelection(if (oldSelectionPos > resultStr.length) resultStr.length else oldSelectionPos)
        } else {
            phoneEditText.setSelection(resultStr.length)
        }
        mSelfChange = false
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
})
```